# Laravel default values for fields in FormRequest

Tags: laravel

Can I set a default value to a not-existing field in a FormRequest in Laravel?

For example, if a field called "timezone" does not exist in the incoming request, it get set to "America/Toronto".

Comment: You typically do this at the database level during migration. E.G. `->default('America/Toronto')`.

Comment: Try and share your code next time. You can get better solutions

Comment: @DigitalDrifter it shouldn't be at the database level, because a request might not deal with database at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I wrote a trait for this, which checks a function called 'defaults' exist in the form request it will replace the default values

```
trait RequestDefaultValuesTrait {


    protected function prepareForValidation(){

        // add default values 
        if( method_exists( $this, 'defaults' ) ) {
            foreach ($this->defaults() as $key => $defaultValue) {
                if (!$this->has($key)) $this->merge([$key => $defaultValue]);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

the thing that you need to do is adding this trait to FormRequest class and then add a function like this:

```
protected function defaults()
{
    return [
        'country'   => 'US',
        'language'  => 'en',
        'timezone'  => 'America/Toronto',
    ];
}
```

Being honest I don't link this method, but It works.

Comment: Why you don't like it?

Answer (score 8):

in request class add

```
public function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->mergeIfMissing([
        'timezone'  => 'America/Toronto'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: it works for $request->all(), but does not work for $request->validated()

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
if(!$request->has('timezone') {
    $request->merge(['timezone' =>'America/Toronto']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure if you need to do it in this way, but if you want to:

```
class CreateUpdateDataFormRequest extends Request
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [];
    }

    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        $data = $this->all();

        if(!isset($data['timezone'])) {
            $data['timezone'] = 'America/Toronto';
            $this->getInputSource()->replace($data);
        }

        // modify data before sending to validator
        return parent::getValidatorInstance();
    }
```